# Activity Component on a Lightning App Page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

I am currently designing a Task List on a Lightning app.

One of my goals is to get the Activity component that you see on Accounts or Contacts to display on this app page when clicking the related to object for the Task.

Is there a way to get a reference of this component without having to rebuild it?

Answer (score 1):

If you weren't using lightning, you could use `apex:relatedList` to display a related list for a record, however, this component is not lightning compatible, and no replacement component has been provided by salesforce.

```
<apex:relatedList list="ActivityHistories"/>
```

You could vote on [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003XCjQAM), but it has very little traction at the time of writing. I would not expect a replacement anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

While not documented, you can instantiate the default Lightning Activity Timeline dynamically (but not in xml markup). The name of this component is "runtime_sales_activities:activityPanel" and it can be created with this javascript,

```
        $A.createComponent("runtime_sales_activities:activityPanel", { recordId: 'XXX' }, function (c, status, message) {
            if (status === "SUCCESS") cmp.set("v.facet", c);
            else reject(message);
        });
```

I'm sure this is not supported by Salesforce and may break in future versions, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately, this component is no referable. you will have to build it from scratch.

In the future, you might want to check your org's component referece guide at:

> https:///componentReference/suite.app

OR

> https:///auradocs/reference.app