# Are you able to load a lighting component within another lighting component

Tags: lightning

Question) How to put an existing lighting component, within another lighting component.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do? In the general sense, yes, you can put components inside components. That's the design and purpose of using components. Without more information, though, we can't really prescribe a specific solution to your problem.

Comment: I wish to put the activities lighting component premade by Salesforce, inside a custom lighting component.

Comment: You can check this un-documented feature -- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/238573/18189. In general, it is not possible